# Bucle Foreach en procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql

¿Se puede tener 2 foreach en un procedimiento almacenado?
ejemplo:

tengo el siguiente siclo que solo lo necesito que haga el proceso 1 sola vez

```
FOREACH
insert into tabla 1 (campo1,campo2,campo3)
select campo1_x,campo2_x,campo3_x
from tabla2
where campo1_n=1
END FOREACH
```

y el segundo foreach es necesario que lo haga de acuerdo a una cantidad parametrizada luego de una consulta

```
FOREACH
insert into tabla 3(campo1,campo2,campo3)
select campo1_x,campo2_x,campo3_x
from tabla2=4
where campo1_n=2
END FOREACH
```

es posible realizarlo de esta manera o existe alguna otra forma .
actualmente solo tengo un foreach, pero en el primer ciclo me esta duplicando los datos, en la primera tabla es solo un encabezado, pero la segunda es un detalle de varios campos, por eso solo necesito que el primero ciclo solo se ejecute 1 vez.

Comment: Si el proceso nada mas se necesita realizar una sola vez, no es necesario implementarlo en un bucle no crees?

Comment: bueno , no realmente 1 vez en general, es 1 vez, por 1 parametros de una consulta anterior, es decir inicialmente se hace una consulta, y si me arrojo resultado 3 ps se debe de aplicar las 3 veces, pero lo que sucede es que como tengo el ciclo sin separarlo, si en la primera consulta que es un encabezado me arroja 3, pero en la segunda consulta que es un detalle, pero arroja 10, en el primer insert me lo inserta las 10 veces o mas

Comment: Si necesitas hacer algo una sola vez no debes usar el ciclo